# How to render the bold/italic text with only a regular font style in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

I'm going to draw the text of bold/italic style in iOS.

I know it's possible to use the various font faces such as xxx-bold, xxx-italic or .ttc font package file.

But I'd like to use a regular font file.

Is this possible? how to?

---

In TextEdit of OS X, it's impossible to select bold/italic style    without the appropriate fonts.

But in Microsoft Office for Mac, it's possible with a regular font file.